# PHP can't read filename which has special character !

Tags: php, file, special-characters

i have problem with `file()` in php. The function can't read a file start with `!` or `$` like `!textfile.txt` or `$textfile.txt`, i try with `fopen()` and it happen as a same way. I have no idea how to solve this. I hope someone can help
Appreciate any help.

Comment: Please specify your operating system, two answers already pointed out problem on `$`, but not `!`

Answer (score 1):

The filename `"$textfile.txt"` will not work as expected because variable interpolation happens in double quotes as a result value of variable `$textfile` will be appended with `.txt` and the result will be used as filename. If `$textfile` is undefined (which mostly is the case), `.txt` will be used as the filename.

To fix this use single quotes around the filename as `'$textfile.txt'` or if you have to use double quotes, escape the `$` as: `"\$textfile.txt"`

But I see no problem with `"!textfile.txt"`

Comment: Just a note -- to actually open "$textfile.txt", either escape the `$` or use single quotes. "\$textfile.txt" and '$textfile.txt' should both work.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo file_get_contents("\$test.txt");
```

Works.

You need to escape special characters or use single quotes.